# VS 2017 with Local reports - The report definition has not been specified

Tags: reporting-services, localreport

I am using vs2017 with ReportViewer 14.0 in a WinForms application.  I have done this before in previous versions of VS without any issues and I am very surprised why I can't make this work this time.

Here is what I have done so far:

- I created a report (RDLC) in the Reports folder which resides in the root of the application.
- I set the BuildAction to None and Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer
- In a new form, I placed the ReportViewer component (called rpt)
- I set the Processing mode to Local
- In the Load event of the form I run the following code:

```html
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Reports\Report.rdlc";
rpt.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;

rpt.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("parTitle", Title));

rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ds", Data));
rpt.Refresh();
```

When I run the app, the form loads but the ReportViewer displays a message: **The report definition has not been specified**

I also tried setting the build action to EmbeddedResource and using:

```html
rpt.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Project.Reports.Report.rdlc";
```

Same result.  I even tried:

```html
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream report = a.GetManifestResourceStream("Project.Reports.Report.rdlc");
rpt.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(report);
```

No difference.  I am always getting this:

[image]

I have been staring at this for several hours now and for the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel quite foolish now, but just as a reference to anyone facing the same issue I am posting the solution here.

Changing

**rpt.Refresh();**

to

**rpt.RefreshReport();**

did the trick.  The report now loads properly.  Refresh is inherited from Control and only invalidates the control, but does not force the report to be processed and rendered.  RefreshReport does just that.

Hope this saves some time to someone.

Comment: Could you mark this as the answer so people don't look through this to try and solve it?

Comment: I can't yet.  It says I have to wait for 2 more days.